# class name change in a dll project wont update?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2017

In a dll solution, I changed the main public class (namebase) to have a better name
 EasyXML.Settings class has now becomme EasyXML.XMLconfig.

```
namespace EasyXML
 {
    public class XMLconfig  // i changed this name and its constructor.
     {
```

When compiling i did a clean solution first and then i compiled both debug and release versions for this .dll

Another project already used the older version, but needed to update to the new version. Thus I removed references to the old dll, and removed old dll, added the new version of the dll, and created a reference to it again.

However somehow that other project doesn't recognize the updated class name XMLconfig. (not on clean builds either), it behaves like if it is cached or so.

I'm not sure, do i need to do additional actions on the dll solution, or on the other project?, to refresh those names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a simple explanation for this:

1. make sure **there aren't any errors** in the second project (otherwise VS most likely fails to update the class names from the dll)
2. make sure by adding the reference of the dll to the second project you are referencing the right file (use solution tab instead of browse)
3. make sure your dll project was actually compiled. (There are several cases where the project didn't compile but the solution build was successful). Check the **modified date** of the dll project output and make sure it isn't an old one.
4. you can go to `project->properties->build->output path` and `project->properties->build events` and make sure the output for the current build configuration points to a right location
5. make sure both projects use the exact **same version of .net framework**

other than that:

1. make sure the class name (XMLConfig) is not exact match of a namespace (EasyXML) otherwise the class might get inaccessible to the VS user
2. make sure there aren't any partial classes in dll project with the same name.
3. make sure there aren't any other classes somewhere else with the same namespace and class name

Comment: you got me at point 4, build path's had been altered, thanks i never thought about it i wasn't suspecting that.

Comment: glad to be of help:)